# Previewing Changes in Bigcommerce Mobile Template

Tags: css, html, mobile, e-commerce, bigcommerce

Hopefully someone can help me out with this.  I've been tasked with giving a mobile template an overhaul on a site that uses BigCommerce.
Does anyone know of an IDE or a windows based browser that would allow me to preview the changes that I make on the fly, preferably via Dreamweaver CC but this isn't a necessity.

Basically I want to completely revamp the homepage so that instead of having a mundane and dreary menu that take up the entire page, I'd like to change it so that I have responsive windows 8 like tiles that one could use to navigate the site.

Answer (score 0):

Since BigCommerce is a paid service you are limited to what is available. You cannot simply download the site and run it on your localhost. I worked on one of those sites before, the best work around I found what to edit in google chrome's inspect element and console "F12" - this way you can make changes directly to the site to see how they render. But keep in mind, F12 is after chrome builds the page and will not match the actual code all the time.

Comment: You can download the entire site and work on it locally, this used to be possible via FTP but they've shifted to WEBDAV now.  I have a local copy of it that I use Dreamweaver to modify and then I can upload it as I please via WEBDAV.

Comment: My question however, related more to the Mobile template of the site.  I was looking for help and was wondering did anyone know of an IDE or program where I could view my changes on the fly.